# Angular - show hidden values from array list via button

Tags: arrays, angular, list

I'm working on a list of values in my web-app. There I'm facing the following problem:

**app.component.html**

*This part of the code shows my array as a list:*

```
<div class="body__tags">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tag of tags; let i=index">
    <li class="tags__list" *ngIf="i<5" [label]="tag"></li>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here I set limit of 5 values in my list. But sometimes there are more than 5 values in the array. How can I add a button "show all" and then display everything in that list?

**app.component.ts**

*This is my ts code:*

```
tags:any[]; 

splitTags() {
  if (this.data.tags != null) {
    this.tags = this.data.tags.split(";");
    console.log(this.tags)
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.splitTags()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `*ngIf` is not the best idea for such scenario.
You should slice the `array` upto 5 and store into another variable.
once User clicks on the button to show all the data, assign the entire `array` to the new variable.

for Example :

```
this.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
this.newData = data.slice(0,5);
```

then in the `component.html` file : ;

```
<div class="body__tags">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tag of newData; let i=index">
    <li class="tags__list" [label]="tag"></li>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

on button click  you should assign entire `data` to `newData` variable.

```
 public showAll(){
      this.newData = this.data;
   }
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nitflf)

Comment: thanks! Works well! What do I have to add to hide the others when I click again on the button?

Comment: Again slice the `data` and assign to `newData`

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: @macintosh11 you can  introduce a `boolean` flag `isAllVisible` . When the flag is `true` ,   slice the array and assign to `newData` else assign the entire data.  in the end `toggle` the `isAllVisible` flag value.

Answer (score -1):

you can keep 5 in some variable and then on click of 'ShowAll()' you can increase the limit